I have a dataset of team members reserving one ( or more) of five rooms. I need a function that can populate a Schedule Sheet dynamically
I have been working on similar projects, but I have a Spreadsheet in Google Sheets called Schedule 2024.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N97T_yPd2M1THOJkZ49dpCIex1ob8AJyBpgWEsawSyU/edit?usp=sharing
It has three sheets ( one is an example sheet to show what I am trying to achieve)
The first sheet ( DataList! ) is a set of data provided by the team members who wish to book the rooms out. They provide the start date, end date and which room or rooms they require.
The second sheet ( Schedule! ) is the destination sheet for the data, and the third Sheet (ExampleSchedule!) is just to show what I am trying to achieve.
I have been researching the BYROW function using Lambda and Sequence and Offset, and then applying a TOCOL function but I am struglling to get all the data I need. Some Genii here helped with an arrayformula using the xlookup function, but I cannot get my head around all the variables. I am no expert but a willing student.


You may try:
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,map(B1:F1,lambda(Λ,let(x,filter(DataList!A:C,trim(DataList!D:D)=substitute(Λ,"Building","Room")),
 join(" / ",ifna(filter(index(x,,1),map(index(x,,2),index(x,,3),lambda(f,q,isbetween(Σ,f,q))))))))))))



You have a trailing space for Room 2 ; so had to use trim function


That is incredible. I will fix the trailing space - thankyou so much. If I change the column headings to Room 1, Room 2 etc, ( which I should have done) will this simplify the function?

Replace this substitute(Λ,"Building","Room") with just Λ
